# How to get child component input element in parent at any time

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-components

I am using parent and child component. In child component I use search box. I need to get search box value at any time on demand. How to get this?

Child Component html - GridViewComponent

```
<input id="successFilter" name='filterInput' type="text" (keyup)="searchSuccess($event)">
```

Parent Component ts

```
@ViewChild(GridviewComponent) grdView: GridviewComponent;
```

wrote above line before constructor

```
this.grdView.filterInput.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

am unable to get input value

Comment: Post your code, show us what you've tried.

Comment: Parent pass input to Child component<==>Child send output event to Parent, I hope you mean something like that

Answer (score 1):

One of the version for your solution is the following(component A  - parent, component B - child):

In component B:
in html file:

```
<input ... [(ngModel)]="inputValue" ...>
```

In componentB.ts file:

```
@Input() needAnswer : ReplaySubject<any>(1);
@Output() hereYourAnswer = new EventEmmiter<any>();
inputValue: string;
private subscription: Subscription;


...

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.needAnswer.subscribe( giveMeAnswer => this.hereYourAnswer.emit(this.inputValue));
}

...
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

In component A, html:

```
<component-b [needAnswer]='needAnswer' (hereYourAnswer)='getAnswer(event$)'></component-b>
```

In componentA.ts file:

```
...
needAnswer = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

...
getInputDataFromComponentB() {
  this.needAnswer.next('give me answer!!! please)');
}
...

getAnswer(answer) {
  console.log(answer, 'here i am');
}

...
```

It is simple to do with RXJS.

Comment: I know you've added the `...`, but you should mention the part for unsubscribing the `needAnswer`-Subject inside the `onDestroy` lifecycle hook because otherwise, the OP could easily build himself a memory leak.

Comment: I fixed a small error for you, you accidentally used the type as a value, also just use the `Subscription` as the type instead of `ISubscription`.